# Google API CORS error on localhost, "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-api, redux-toolkit

I'm building a small MERN stack application which will contain calendar. The intention with the calendar is to sync it with multiple employees' Google Calendars for scheduling purposes.

I've started testing the Google Calendar API, and their test code here works just fine when I run it directly with Node: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/nodejs

However, now I'm trying to configure a button which will trigger a request from React to the Express backend and hit a route (and use the subsequent callback route) in order to authorize the employee's (the Operator) work Google account and capture the necessary credentials to store in the database. This way, the app can save the auth and refresh tokens needed for each Operator to keep the Google Calendars continuously synced with the application's calendar. This doesn't seem to work, while I'm in development at least, for some reason I keep getting this error:

`Access to fetch at '<the generated oauth2 url>' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3500/api/auth/<the email>') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I've thought of instead doing this all in the frontend and sending it to my database from there, but that seems insecure.

I set up cors and I have 'http://localhost:3000' listed as an allowed origin, it works for everything else but this.

I've also tried using a proxy, but I can't seem to get my frontend to use it. I've tried the http-proxy-middleware package, and I've tried simply adding "proxy": "http://localhost:3500" to my package.json. None of it takes, console logging the request origins on my server show they are still coming from localhost:3000.

I've been toiling away at this for a while now, and I can't seem to get past it.

This is the query builder from the apiSlice (this works as the route is definitely called. I think the issue might actually be what I'm getting back from the auth redirect?):

```
    getOperatorAuth: builder.query({
      query: (operatorEmail) => ({
        url:`/api/auth/${operatorEmail}`,
        validateStatus: (response, result) => {
          return response.status === 200 && !result.isError
        },
      }),
```

Here are the routes:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const operatorsController = require('../controllers/operatorsController')

router.route('/auth/:operatorEmail')
  .get(operatorsController.getGoogleAuth)

router.route('/callback')
  .get(operatorsController.getGoogleAuthCallback)

module.exports = router
```

And here are the functions they call:

```
const getGoogleAuth = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers.origin)
  console.log("requesting auth route")
  const operatorEmail = req.params.operatorEmail;
  const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri);
  const authorizeUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
    state: JSON.stringify({ operatorEmail }),
  });
  res.redirect(authorizeUrl);
}

const getGoogleAuthCallback =async (req, res) => {
  console.log("google callback")
  const code = req.query.code;
  const state = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(req.query.state));
  const operatorEmail = state.operatorEmail;
  const data = querystring.stringify({
    code: code,
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
  });
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
      data,
      { headers: headers }
    );
    const accessToken = response.data.access_token;
    const refreshToken = response.data.refresh_token;

    // Store the access token and refresh token in MongoDB
    const operatorAuth = new OperatorAuth({
      email: operatorEmail,
      accessToken: accessToken,
      refreshToken: refreshToken
    });

    await operatorAuth.save();

    res.send('Access token and refresh token received and stored');
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error.message);
  }

}
```

And CORS setup:

Server.js

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const corsOptions = require('./config/corsOptions')
const connectDB = require('./config/dbConn')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)

connectDB()

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use(express.json())

app.use(cookieParser())

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use('/api', require('./routes/apiRoutes'))
```

corsOptions.js

```
const allowedOrigins = require('./allowedOrigins')

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  },
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

module.exports = corsOptions
```

and allowedOrigins.js:

```
const allowedOrigins = [
  'http://localhost:3000'
]

module.exports = allowedOrigins
```

Comment: You can try serving your frontend by your server so they both have the same port. But if you allowed cors it should work. Maybe you should share that part of the code where you enable cors.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that would probably help ha. I've added the cors setup. My current work around is to send the generated auth url back to the front end in the response and redirect to the Oauth screen from there instead. After that, the callback route works and the so does the rest. Then I have the callback route do the redirect that I want back from the Oauth screen to my application. I would like to avoid having to do it this way though.